# Problema upload php

Tags: php, arquivo, upload

Alguém sabe me dizer o porque do arquivo não estar sendo recebido na pasta de destino?

```
private $id;
private $entrada;
private $saida;
private $status;

public function __construct($bd) {
    $this->bd = $bd;        
}

public function construirObjeto($entrada, $saida, $status) {
    $this->entrada = $entrada;
    $this->saida = $saida;
    $this->status = $status;
}    

public function inserir(){

    $origem = $_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"];


    $entradaa = "emboss/aaindexextract/" . $_FILES["arquivo"]["name"];


    if($entradaa){                 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO caminhoarquivo(entrada, saida, status) VALUES ('$entradaa', 'NULL', 'SOLICITADO')";

        $this->bd->executarSql($sql);
    }else{
        echo "Erro!";
    }

    //salva foto no diretorio
    move_uploaded_file($origem, $entradaa);
```

}

Comment: Verifique as permissões da pasta de destino

Comment: Os dados estão sendo inseridos no banco de dados?

Comment: sim os dados estão sendo inserido só que sem o $_FILES["arquivo"]["name"]  somente emboss/aaindexextract/

Comment: faça um debug então, use: print_r($_FILES["arquivo"] ou var_dump($_FILES["arquivo"]

Comment: Já realizei o debug, não esta vindo nada no $_FILES["arquivo"] .

Comment: Então veja se na tag form do html tem o atributo: enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Muito obrigado ai pela ajuda, havia esquecido mesmo de colocar o enctype="multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solução do problema**

falta do atributo: enctype, na tag form

```
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```